# go(golang) erro ao dar o comando go install - unexpected directory layout

Tags: visual-studio-code, golang, variáveis-de-ambiente

Sou novato no go(golang) estou tentando iniciar uma aplicação porem sem sucesso, ele me retorna o seguinte erro ao dar o comando go install:

```
unexpected directory layout:
        import path: github.com/gorilla/handlers
        root: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src
        dir: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api\vendor\github.com\gorilla\handlers
        expand root: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src
        expand dir: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api\vendor\github.com\gorilla\handlers
        separator: \
```

minha versão :

```
 go1.10 windows/amd64
```

Comment: não deu certo...

Comment: Qual é a estrutura dos arquivos?

Comment: a GOPATH "D:\BitBucketERN\GO" e a GORROT "D:\GO\" e a estrutura do projeto "D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api"

Comment: tente adicionar copiar o `github.com/gorilla/handlers` para `D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\github.com\gorilla\handlers`

Comment: já estava copiado nesse diretorio

Comment: Tente copiar para `D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api\vendor\github.com\gorilla\handlers` então. Esse erro está diretamente relacionado a localização dos arquivos, só precisa achar a configuração certa. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428744/golang-unexpected-directory-layout#45429321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina as variáveis de ambiente GOROOT sendo a pasta onde você realizou a instalação, no meu caso instalei diretamente no C:/Go, já a GOPATH onde você vai programar efetivamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]